Can I change collation_connection permanently? Having issues running queries in Navicat on a remote MariaDB server
I try to have everything utf8 with utf8mb4_unicode_ci collation.  As far as I can see, everything is.
But occasionally in Navicat, I get an error message about an illegal mix of collations - that and utf8mb4_general_ci.
SHOW VARIABLES tells me that collation_connection is the culprit, as it is indeed set to utf8mb4_general_ci.
I can easily change it on the fly to be able to run the query I want to run, but I'd rather it just worked all of the time.
I tried setting it in my.cnf.d/server.conf under [mariadb] and it wouldn't even start, saying it was an unknown variable.
(The same queries run without issue both on the command line and in my browser.)
